# Cannot get JavaFX to work in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use `JavaFX` in Eclipse but whenever I use any of it's Classes it doesn't recognize the type. To clarify I get the message `"Dropshadow cannot be resolved to a type"`

This happens not only with Dropshadow, but with any of the `JavaFX` classes. The IDE won't give me an option to import it and when I try and to type it in manually it isn't recognized.  In using `JSE 8u25`, which apparently has it included.

In looking around I see that the `.jar file` can be added manually, but I would like to know if something within my IDE isn't configured right, because it should be working. Can anybody give me a hand with this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you added it to the Build Path?

Comment: what version of Eclipse are you using? And what version of JavaFX?

Comment: How are you referencing it?

Comment: @CaffeineToCode Well by the sounds of it, it looks like they've just plopped it in there and tried to run it. :/

Comment: My guess is he didn't add it to the build path. I can't be sure though, so I don't want to post an answer.

Comment: @CaffeineToCode Doing it now. :P

Answer (score 2):

So I finally got it working, the solution was to install the eclipse plugin found here:

http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

The directions are pretty good, I just followed them as written and got it up and running.

Answer (score 1):

## Adding to Build Path

Your problem here, is that you just dropped your `.jar` file right in there, and tried using it. You need to **add** it to the project. To do so, follow the below steps:

1. Add the `.jar` file to your project **folder** (not `src`) via. copy/paste or simply drag/drop.
2. Right click on the `.jar` file once it's inside your project.
3. Press `Build Path > Add To Build Path`

What you have/will done, is adding the `.jar` to the project itself. Theres a difference between having it **in** your project, and having it **a part** of your project.

Now you can `import`, `extend`, `implement`, whatever you need.

---

## Removing from Build Path

Ok, so you found a better library for what you want, no longer need the library or made your own, and you want to delete your `.jar`.

Well, firstly, it's *still* **a part** of your project, so you need to remove it from the Build Path first.

1. Right click on the `.jar` file.
2. Press `Build Path > Remove from Build Path`

Your `.jar` is *still* **inside** your project, but no longer **a part** of it.

Now you may go ahead and delete it without worry.

Comment: Thanks for the answers all. I guess where I'm getting hung up here is that I was under the impression that JavaFX was part of the JDK I have (8u25), and therefore shouldn't need to add the .jar at all (just like using anything else from the API). Am I way off here?

Comment: "The JavaFX Download Section has moved

 As of JDK 7u6 JavaFX is included with the standard JDK and JRE bundles.  Please download the JDK or JRE to use JavaFX. If you are looking for the JavaFX Scene Builder download you will find it in the "Additional Resources" section of the main Java SE Download Page


 Please update your links to the new location.." --From the oracle JavaFX downloads page.

Comment: @user3226170 I'm sorry, what are you asking?

Comment: Well it seems that most of the suggestions I have received all have to do with adding the .jar file manually and then adding it to the build path, however it is my understanding (as per the above quote from Oracle's site) that there should be no requirement to add the .jar, it should be included in current JDKs. In fact, the quote I added above came from the link to the JavaFX .jar download, which is no longer available. So I guess my question is, why isn't my IDE recognizing JavaFX if it part of the JDK that I have installed? Thanks.

Comment: @user3226170 Ah! I understand now. Ok. What JRE annd JDK version are you running?

Comment: jre1.8.0_25 and JDK 8u25

Comment: @user3226170 I'm reinstalling Java and testing now, but in the mean time, I'm ***pretty*** sure that JavaFX is a standalone `.jar`.

Comment: Anybody ever come up with a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to solve your issue is to right click your project, go to properties > java build path then select the tab where it says Libraries.
You have to select that library you have in there > click the button EDIT then select from there Workspace default JRE . You need to have at least java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Step1 Download JavaFX zip folder and place it into save folder like document folder

https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
Step 2 File -> New Project -> Java Project

Step3 Right on Project Click on properties -> Click on Libraries Add Library --> Add New --> Add External Jars

Step4 - Remove module-info.java file from your project

Step5 - Set the VM Arguments Click on Run--> Run Configuration --> Arguments

Add Path Like this (my sdk present in documents folder)

--module-path /Users/MICROSOFT/Documents/javafx-sdk-17.0.6/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Thanks